# Не разбивается строка на слова в C++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Возникла проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "n";
    cout << endl;
    int n=0;
    int i=0;
    cin >> n;
    cin.get();
    string mass[n];
    vector<string> arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        cout << i;
        getline(cin, mass[i]);
    }

    string str = "";
    str = mass[0];
    //getline(cin, str);
    istringstream ist(str);

    for (string word; ist >> word; cout << word << endl);

    return 0;
}
```

Я ввожу строку в массив и пытаюсь первый элемент массива разбить на слова.
Первое слово теряется и в конце появляется какой то мусор.
Но если я введу строку с клавиатуры, та же самое строка бьется идеально.
Где я ошибся? На плюсах ранее не работал. Мой ЯП - Java.

Comment: https://ideone.com/I5chCC - не видно, чтоб не работало. Вы тот под привели? В этом проблема в том только, что `string mass[n];` не стандарт, а расширение G++. Ну и `cin.get();` в общем случае не сработает - лучше `ignore`. По незадействованному `vector<string> arr[n];` у меня ощущение, что вы с ним пытались работать, и нахомутали - потому что это массив векторов, а не вектор с n строками...

Comment: Большое спасибо. Действительно работает мой код. Если добавить строку arr[1].push_back("qw");
то не работает. Как они взаимосвязаны, не могу понять.

Comment: Вы бы привели **полностью** неработающий код - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example